# Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 -- TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition for IndexOf(string)

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to rework old Azure Storage Client 1.7 code into version 2.0 code.

Originally I had the following query:

```
TableServiceContext context = ...;

TableServiceQuery<LogData> query = null;
            query = (from d in data where 
            d.Message.IndexOf(searchString) > -1
            select d).AsTableServiceQuery<LogData>(context);            
List<LogData> selectedData = new List<LogData>();

selectedData = query.Execute().ToList<LogData>();
```

How would I rework this IndexOf condition into 2.0 API syntax? I've been able to rework most of my queries, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this one as a TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition like so:

```
CloudTable table = ...;

string filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey",QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, 1000);
TableQuery<LogData> query = (new TableQuery<LogData>()).Where(filter);
List<LogData> selectedData = new List<LogData>();
selectedData = query.Execute().ToList<LogData>();
```

I've read numerous documentations put out by Microsoft, none of which address this case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching within text is not supported by Azure Tables.

There are two possible options:

1. Perform this operation on client side. In this scenario, you will need to fetch all the relevant data on the client side and then apply this 2nd level filter. If you have too much data then this will become really cumbersome as you're downloading a large amount of data.
2. Use Azure Search. You can connect your Azure Table Storage to an Azure Search Service index and then perform the search using Search Service. There you will be able to do all the fuzzy searches.